# Create endless loop animation using ffmpeg using only certain frames

Tags: loops, animation, ffmpeg

I can create an animated gif using the commands below.

```
ffmpeg -i wrist_0001.png -vf palettegen=16 palette.png

ffmpeg -i wrist_%04d.png -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=20,scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" logo.gif
```

What I'm trying to know how to do is:

1. Create another animated gif using just the first 20 frames and the animation loops endlessly **(no pausing at the end of the animation)**.
2. Create another animated gif using just the first 20 frames where the **animation plays then pauses at the end for 3 seconds then continues. (endlessly)** Example: (play animation - pause 3 seconds - play animation - pause 3 seconds - play animation - pause 3 seconds...)

**Note: I'm trying to avoid having to type in wrist_0001.png wrist_0002.png...is there away to do wrist_0001.png to wrist_0020.png?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create another animated gif using just the first 20 frames and the animation loops endlessly (no pausing at the end of the animation):

   ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i wrist_%04d.png -filter_complex "scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=max_colors=16[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -frames:v 20 -loop 0 20framesloop.gif
   ```

   - When using a set of images as the input set the frame rate with the `-framerate` [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) input option. Your original command is defaulting to 25 fps and then using the fps filter to convert to 20 fps meaning frames are being dropped.
   - `-loop 0` is the default for the GIF muxer, but I added it to show how it works if you want to change the looping. 0 means infinite loop.
   - This example makes the GIF in one command as shown in [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031/)
2. Create another animated gif using just the first 20 frames where the animation plays then pauses at the end for 3 seconds then continues. (endlessly)

   Most efficient method is to re-mux the GIF from the previous step:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i 20framesloop.gif -c copy -final_delay 300 -loop 0 3secpause.gif
   ```

   `-final_delay 300` takes a value in centiseconds, so 3 seconds is 300 centiseconds. See `ffmpeg -h muxer=gif` for more info.